# ultraToolbarsManager not Visible after loaded form

Tags: c#-4.0, toolbar, infragistics

I'm having problems when programming with Infragistics need help

the problem here is the original before loading the form I set ultraToolbarsManager.Tools [Key] .SharedProps.Visible = false and load form when finished I should set ultraToolbarsManager.Tools [Key] .SharedProps.Visible = true but still not show ultraToolbarsManager while disabled

Here is the original code

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.ultraToolbarsManager1.Tools.Count; i++)                           
{    
     this.ultraToolbarsManager1.Tools[i].SharedProps.Visible = false; 
}
```

Here is the complete code after load form

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.ultraToolbarsManager1.Tools.Count; i++){                                                                   
     this.ultraToolbarsManager1.Tools[i].SharedProps.Visible = true;
}
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The Tools collection of UltraToolbarsManager is containing all the tools you may have in your application. To show any of these tools you need to add them to toolbar, menu, ribbon and so on. The main idea is that you may have the same tool on a toolbar and on a menu. For example, you may have Save button on the toolbar and Save button on your File menu. For this button, you will need only one tool in your tools collection. So if you just added some tools without put them on menu toolbar and so on you will not see them.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,
The time I had to use all the controls, but the problem to be solved after the load form that is completed will implement the task and need to hide, it does control (UltraToolbarsManager)

Comment: For example, members is authorized functions, after logging only show functions allowed

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had resolved, to reload this control to set the first attribute

```
ultraToolbarsManager1.BeginUpdate();
this.ultraToolbarsManager1.Tools [key] .SharedProps.ResetVisible ();
ultraToolbarsManager1.EndUpdate();
```